# Why cannot I add new list in a table in angularJS 1.x?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-1.5, angularjs-1.6, angularjs-model

I have example code below where I am supposed to create a list of items.

```
 <div ng-hide="listTrigger">
                    <!--FIRST TABLE-->
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th sortable="code" class="sortable">
                                Product Name
                            </th>
                            <th sortable="placed" class="sortable">
                                Qty
                            </th>
                            <th class="st-sort-disable th-dropdown">
                                Price
                            </th>
                            <th sortable='total.value' class="sortable">
                                Split
                            </th>
                            <th>

                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr grid-item>
                            <td width="40%">
                                <select class="form-control" ng-model="prod.uid">
                                    <option selected disabled>Select Product</option>
                                    <option ng-repeat="product in products | orderBy : 'name'" ng-value="product.uid" >{{product.name}}</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                            <td width="20%">
                                <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="prod.qty" class="form-control">

                            </td>
                            <td width="20%">
                                <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="prod.price" class="form-control">
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%">
                                <input type="number" min="1" max="100" ng-model="prod.split" class="form-control">
                            </td>
                            <td width="10%"><button ng-click="addNewProduct(prod.id)" class="form-control">Add</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>


     <!--SECOND TABLE-->
                    <table ng-show="newProducts.length!=0"  class="table">

                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th  >
                                Product Name
                            </th>
                            <th  >
                                Qty
                            </th>
                            <th >
                                Price
                            </th>
                            <th >
                                Split
                            </th>
                            <th>

                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="newProduct in newProducts">
                            <td width="60%" ng-bind="newProduct.uid"></td>
                            <td width="10%" ng-bind="newProduct.qty"></td>
                            <td width="10%"ng-bind="newProduct.price"></td>
                            <td width="10%" ng-bind="newProduct.split"></td>
                            <td width="10%"><button ng-show="newProducts.length!=0" ng-click="removeProduct(newProduct.uid)">X</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Output
[but whatever i type in the textbox of first table is coming just like that in second table. It is supposed to come list by list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSQg9.png)

In JS I am getting all details from input fields and settinf to an object prod and then pushing it in to an array newProducts.
Later in the table I am using ng-repeat to repeat items in newProducts array. The top table and bottom table are connected in no other way and I cannot figure out why values are chaging in bottom table when they are changed in input fields. Also while trying to add it one more time, it throws an error.

```
jquery.js:4409 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=newProduct%20in%20newPr…0a-42d3-949e-3e8e59ac2be9%22%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A359%22%7D
```

Here is the JS to add new item

```
//function to add new product while creating
        $scope.addNewProduct= function(id){
            $scope.newProducts.push($scope.prod);
            console.log("product array-"+JSON.stringify( $scope.newProducts));

        }
```

I tried console.log to log newProducts array in console, it is getting updated with new array , but not showing up in second table. Please help!

Comment: //function to add new product while creating
            $scope.addNewProduct= function(id){
                $scope.newProducts.push($scope.prod);
                console.log("product array-"+JSON.stringify( 
                $scope.newProducts));

            }

Answer (score 1):

use angular copy.
angular $scopes are two way binded.. the changes u make in first table will be reflected in second table as you are pushing $scope.prod which is two way binded.

Answer (score 0):

Using $scope can be very tricky. I'm not the best in Angular but i have no idea

```
$scope.newProducts.push($scope.prod);
```

if you are using here the $scope of the function or the $scope of the Controller.

Put in at the very top of your Controller "var vm=$scope", and in your html use "Controller as vm".

So if you are then there, we can see if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Angular variables are reference type. So you can use angular.copy() to overcome from this issue. Below the code.

```js
$scope.addNewProduct= function(id){
      var products = angular.copy($scope.prod);
      $scope.newProducts.push(products);
      console.log("product array-"+JSON.stringify( $scope.newProducts));
}
```

Hope it will help you thanks.